# How to pass value to the javascript on partial post back using updatePanel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I do some query in the code behind and asign the value to a hidden field. how can I pass the same value to the Javascript. I dont want to use session as It is not updating on partial page load.

This is the code I used:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     //Draw a pie
    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
        data.addRows(4);

        data.setValue(1, 0, 'Not Received');
        data.setValue(1, 1, Value1);
        data.setValue(2, 0, 'Received');
        data.setValue(2, 1, Value2);
        data.setValue(3, 0, 'Read');
        data.setValue(3, 1, Value3);
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, { width: 450,backgroundColor:'#DCDCDC', height: 300, title: 'Message Status' });

      // to draw a bar
        var progress1 = new RGraph.VProgress('progress1', Value4, 100);
        progress1.Set('chart.colors', [Value5]);
        progress1.Set('chart.tickmarks', false);
        progress1.Set('chart.margin', 3);
        progress1.Set('chart.tickmarks.inner', false);
        progress1.Set('chart.label.inner', true);
        progress1.Set('chart.gutter.left', 20);
        progress1.Set('chart.gutter.right', 40);
        progress1.Set('chart.tickmarks', true);
        progress1.Set('chart.units.post', '%');
        progress1.Draw();
        }
```

The Value in the last line should be passed from the hidden field. pls give me some code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on when this code is being called, you could do something like this:

```
data.setValue(1, 1, "<%=ServerSideFunction()%>");
```

**EDIT**

You said that you're assigning the value to the hidden field, so why don't you just retrieve the value from the HiddenField in Javascript?:

JavaScript:

```
var value = document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>").value;
```

jQuery:

```
var value = $("#<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>").val();
```

If you need to get a value that won't be available until the page has posted back, I would look into using PageMethods.

Here's an article that explains how to use PageMethods:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/10/04/asp-net-ajax-pagemethods.aspx

Comment: Are you suggesting me to call a method to get the value.? I have to pass many value to the JS Cant use seperate method for each value.

Comment: I was just going by your example. If you can expand on your question, I will update my answer.

Comment: I have to pass 5 value to my Javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send server-side data to the client on page load you can either use the .NET [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) class to include script on the page or do it inline (e.g. `var value = <%= Value %>`).

Here is an example of how to include script in your response using the ScriptManager:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), Me.GetType.Name(), script, True)
```

The object `script` in this case is a string which contains the actual script you want added to the page.  An example of what `script` would be equal to:

```
"var data = 1234"
```

It would then be included in the response of your page (inside the form element) like this:

```
<script>var data = 1234</script>
```

Comment: I have a script manager in my page as i have update panel. Can you give me a code example